# Passing the Map as argument in a function and get the keys w.r.t the values in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Here Map is a map data consisting of the key and value pairs like

```
Map = # {"a" => "Apple","b" =>"bat","c" =>"cat ",
  "d" => "dog","e" => "eagle","f" => "fan ","g" => "goat",
  "h" =>"hat","i" =>"ink","j" =>"jar","k" =>"king","l" =>"lion ",
  "m" =>"madam","n" =>"nike","o" => "orange","p" =>"pot",
  "q" =>"queue ","r" =>"rat","s" =>"snake","t" =>"tea ",
  "u" =>"umbrella","v" =>"van ","w" =>"wolf ","x" =>"xperia ",
  "y" =>"yawk","z" =>"zoo "}
```

I am trying to to print the following below:

Example:

- Input: Apple nike goat lion eagle
- Expected output: Angle.

Tried code:

```
-module(main).
-export([start/1,func/2]).
start(Str) ->
   Map = # {"a" => "Apple","b" =>"bat","c" =>"cat ","d" => "dog","e" => "eagle","f" => "fan ","g" => "goat","h" =>"hat","i" =>"ink","j" =>"jar","k" =>"king","l" =>"lion ","m" =>"madam","n" =>"nike","o" => "orange","p" =>"pot","q" =>"queue ","r" =>"rat","s" =>"snake","t" =>"tea ","u" =>"umbrella","v" =>"van ","w" =>"wolf ","x" =>"xperia ","y" =>"yawk","z" =>"zoo "},
  Chunks = string:tokens(Str, [$\s]),
  io:format("~n~p",[Chunks]),
  L = func(Chunks,Map),
  io:format("~p",[L]).
func([],#{}) ->
 io:format("~nCompleted~n");
func([First | Rest], Map) ->
    Fun = fun(K, V, Acc) -> 
               if V == First -> [K | Acc]; 
                   true -> Acc
                   end 
                end,
     maps:fold(Fun, [], Map), 
  func(Rest, Map).
```

Anyone please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you this. Of course to be efficient you should store the reverse dictionary somewhere, in a server state for example.

```
1> % Enter the dictionary
1> Map = # {"a" => "apple","b" =>"bat","c" =>"cat","d" => "dog","e" => "eagle","f" => "fan","g" => "goat","h" =>"hat","i" =>"ink","j" =>"jar","k" =>"king","l" =>"lion","m" =>"madam","n" =>"nike","o" => "orange","p" =>"pot","q" =>"queue","r" =>"rat","s" =>"snake","t" =>"tea","u" =>"umbrella","v" =>"van","w" =>"wolf","x" =>"xperia","y" =>"yawk","z" =>"zoo"}.         
#{"a" => "apple","b" => "bat","c" => "cat","d" => "dog",
  "e" => "eagle","f" => "fan","g" => "goat","h" => "hat",
  "i" => "ink","j" => "jar","k" => "king","l" => "lion",
  "m" => "madam","n" => "nike","o" => "orange","p" => "pot",
  "q" => "queue","r" => "rat","s" => "snake","t" => "tea",
  "u" => "umbrella","v" => "van","w" => "wolf",
  "x" => "xperia","y" => "yawk","z" => "zoo"}
2> % You have a dictionary letters to things while you need a dictionary things to letters. Let's revert it
2> L = maps:to_list(Map). % First trasform into list
[{"a","apple"},
 {"b","bat"},                         
 {"c","cat"},
 {"d","dog"},
 {"e","eagle"},
 {"f","fan"},
 {"g","goat"},
 {"h","hat"},
 {"i","ink"},
 {"j","jar"},
 {"k","king"},
 {"l","lion"},
 {"m","madam"},
 {"n","nike"},
 {"o","orange"},
 {"p","pot"},
 {"q","queue"},
 {"r","rat"},
 {"s","snake"},
 {"t","tea"},
 {"u","umbrella"},
 {"v","van"},
 {"w","wolf"},
 {"x","xperia"},
 {"y","yawk"},
 {"z","zoo"}]
3> IL = [{V,K} || {K,V} <- L]. % exchange Key and Values
[{"apple","a"},
 {"bat","b"},                         
 {"cat","c"},
 {"dog","d"},
 {"eagle","e"},
 {"fan","f"},
 {"goat","g"},
 {"hat","h"},
 {"ink","i"},
 {"jar","j"},
 {"king","k"},
 {"lion","l"},
 {"madam","m"},
 {"nike","n"},
 {"orange","o"},
 {"pot","p"},
 {"queue","q"},
 {"rat","r"},
 {"snake","s"},
 {"tea","t"},
 {"umbrella","u"},
 {"van","v"},
 {"wolf","w"},
 {"xperia","x"},
 {"yawk","y"},
 {"zoo","z"}]
4> IM = maps:from_list(IL). % build the expected dictionary
#{"apple" => "a","bat" => "b","cat" => "c","dog" => "d",                                                                                                             
  "eagle" => "e","fan" => "f","goat" => "g","hat" => "h",
  "ink" => "i","jar" => "j","king" => "k","lion" => "l",
  "madam" => "m","nike" => "n","orange" => "o","pot" => "p",
  "queue" => "q","rat" => "r","snake" => "s","tea" => "t",
  "umbrella" => "u","van" => "v","wolf" => "w",
  "xperia" => "x","yawk" => "y","zoo" => "z"}
5> Input =  ["apple", "nike", "goat", "lion", "eagle"]. % define a test input
["apple","nike","goat","lion","eagle"]
6> lists:reverse(lists:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> [V] = maps:get(X,IM), [V|Acc] end, [], Input)). % translate
"angle"
7>
```

Answer (score 2):

You say your input is:

```
Apple nike goat lion eagle
```

but that isn't an erlang term, so your input is nonsensical.

If your input is actually the string `"Apple nike goat lion eagle"`, then I'm not sure why you need your map because you can just extract the first letter of each word:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

get_first_letters_of_words(Sentence) ->
    Words = string:split(Sentence, "\s", all),
    Result = get_first_letters(Words, _Acc=[]),
    io:format("~p~n", [Result]).

get_first_letters([ [Int|_Ints] | Words], Acc) ->
    get_first_letters(Words, [Int|Acc]);
get_first_letters([], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

In the shell:

```
63> c(a).                                                      
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

64> a:get_first_letters_of_words("Apple nike goat lion eagle").
"Angle"
ok
```

You can read about how to work with strings below.  The list of words returned by [string:split/3](https://erldocs.com/21.0/stdlib/string.html?i=0&search=string:sp#split/2) is actually a list where each element is a list of integers, e.g.

```
[ [97,98,99], [100,101,102] ]
```

The function `get_first_letters/2` might be easier to understand if you write it like this:

```
get_first_letters([Word|Words], Acc) ->
    [Int|_Ints] = Word,
    get_first_letters(Words, [Int|Acc]);
get_first_letters([], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

It also makes no sense to create a map where the words are the values and the first letters are the keys.  Instead, you would create a map where the words are the keys and the values are the first letters, then you could call [maps:get/2](https://erldocs.com/21.0/stdlib/maps.html?i=0&search=maps:get#get/2) with a word to look up the first letter.

If you actually have a map where a word/value is associated with more than one key, then things are a little trickier.  The following example retrieves all the keys associated with a word:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

get_code_for_words(Sentence) ->
    Words = string:split(Sentence, "\s", all),
    LettersWords = # {"a" => "Apple",
                      "b" => "bat",
                      "c" => "cat",
                      "x" => "bat"},
    Result = get_codes(Words, LettersWords, _AllCodes=[]),
    io:format("~p~n", [Result]).
    
get_codes([Word|Words], Map, AllCodes) ->
    NewAllCodes = maps:fold(fun([K],V,Acc) ->
                   case V =:= Word of
                        true -> [K|Acc];
                        _    -> Acc
                   end
               end,
               AllCodes,
               Map),

    get_codes(Words, Map, NewAllCodes);
get_codes([], _Map, AllCodes) ->
    lists:reverse(AllCodes).
```

In the shell:

```
79> c(a).                                 
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

80> a:get_code_for_words("Apple bat cat").
"abxc"
ok
```

---

In erlang, a string is just a shortcut for creating a list of integers, where the integers in the list are the ascii codes of the characters in the string.

```
8> "abc" =:= [97, 98, 99].
true
```

You may not like that, but that's the way it is: a double quoted string tells erlang to create a list of integers.  The shell is misleading because sometimes the shell prints out the string "abc" as `"abc"` instead of `[97, 98, 99]`.  To prevent the shell from misleading you, you can execute `shell:strings(false)` in the shell, and then the shell will always output lists of integers for strings:

```
12> shell:strings(false).
true

13> "abc".                     
[97,98,99]
```

That will continue for the rest of your shell session (or until you execute `shell:strings(true)`. You can still explicitly tell the shell to print a string if you want:

```
16> io:format("~p~n", ["abc"]).
"abc"
ok
```

When you use `[Head|Tail]` to match a list of integers, e.g. a double quoted string, `Head` will match an integer:

```
9> [Head|Tail] = "abc".
"abc"

10> Head.
97
```

The problem is that the keys in your map are strings--not integers. The easiest way to handle that is to turn the integer into a string by inserting it into a list:

```
11> [Head].
"a"
```

Here is an example:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

get_words(ListOfInts) ->  %% ListOfInts can be a double quoted string
    LettersWords = # {"a" => "Apple",
                      "b" => "bat",
                      "c" => "cat",
                      "d" => "dog"},
    Words = get_words(ListOfInts, LettersWords, _Acc=[]),
    io:format("~p~n", [Words]).

get_words([Int|Ints], Map, Acc) ->
    Letter = [Int],
    Word = maps:get(Letter, Map),
    get_words(Ints, Map, [Word|Acc]);
get_words([], _Map, Acc) -> Acc.
```

In the shell:

```
3> c(a).
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

4> a:start("cad").
["dog","Apple","cat "]
ok
```

If you would like the results in the same order as the letters in your input string, then return `lists:reverse(Acc)` instead of `Acc`.

If you want to display each word--not a list of words, like this:

```
 "cat" "Apple" "dog"
```

you can do this:

```
show_results(Words) ->
    lists:foreach(fun(Word) -> io:format("~p ", [Word]) end,
                 Words),
    io:format("~n").
```

If you don't want to display the quotes, for instance:

```
cat Apple dog
```

you can use the `~s` control sequence:

```
show_results(Words) ->
    lists:foreach(fun(Word) -> io:format("~s ", [Word]) end,
                 Words),
    io:format("~n").
```